# Software showing detailed differences in files given two directories

Tags: linux, diff

What I want:

- recursively compare all files which are in both directories
- option to ignore multiple specific directories (e.g. `node_modules` and `.git`)
- highlighting of differences on word/character level (e.g. `abc` changes to `axc`, so `x` will be highlighted)
- runs on Linux
- free (as in legally obtainable and usable for unlimited time for any purpose without any cost)

Preferably under an open source license.

I am using `diff` and while it matches most of the requirements, it can't show differences in line, just lines that changed (no quick way to tell, what changed on that line).
I also tried `kdiff3` which (at least looking at `--help`) can't compare directories.
It doesn't matter to me if it's CLI or GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff` as you did, and then pipe the output into [`diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) , which is free.

I have two files , f1.txt and f2.txt . they are 3 lines long, and they differ only in one character in line 2.

The diff-so-fancy output looks like this:

[image: diff-so-fancy]

I had to add the screenshot to display the colors as *I* see them. Perhpas they look different on your computer.